# Nginx separate apps in subdirectories

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I am trying to move an app from apache server to nginx. The problem is that there are multiple apps in subdirectories and I can't find a proper way to configure the server.

What I need:

- `www.example.com` serves from `/srv/app`
- `www.example.com/sub1` serves from `/srv/app/sub1`
- `www.example.com/sub2` serves from `/srv/app/sub2`

Each of the apps need the same config, so I extracted that in a snippet:

```
# snippets/app.conf

index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

location /system {
    return 403;
}

# [a couple of other 403s excluded]

# Pass non-file URI to index.php
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

# Use PHP
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}

# Hide .htaccess
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

And in the main server file:

```
# [non-www and http redirects]

server {
    # [listen directives]

    server_name www.example.com;

    root /srv/app;

    include snippets/app.conf;

    location /sub1 {
        root /srv/app/sub1;
        include snippets/app.conf;
    }

    # [other sub-apps included in the same way]

    # [ssl stuff]
}
```

However, this gives me an error:

> nginx: [emerg] location "/system" is outside location "/sub1" in /etc/nginx/snippets/app.conf:5

It's obvious from the error that `/system` is interpreted as being "absolute" `www.example.com/system` instead of the nested `www.example.com/sub1/system`. Can I somehow specify that I want the nested locations to be considered relative? Or I just have to repeat the whole near-identical config for every sub-app changing the prefixes?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that most of the repeating is not necessary in nginx.

The directives to use fastcgi for `.php` and hide `/.ht` files were already regexes so they affect everything. It's enough to specify `index` once and the default there stuff was redundant if I only want to use `index.php`.

As all the apps are nested on the filesystem in the same way as on web, specifying root was not necessary either.

What surprised me was that `location ^~ /(system|data)/ { ... }` matches not only `www.example.com/system/`, but also `www.example.com/sub1/system/`. I thought that `^~` should match only if the location start matches the regex...

```
# [non-www and http redirects]

server {
    # [listen directives]

    server_name www.example.com;

    root /srv/app;

    index index.php;

    location ^~ /(system|data)/ {
        return 403;
    }

    # Use PHP
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    # Pass non-file URI to index.php for all locations
    location /sub1/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /sub1/index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /sub2/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /sub2/index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # [other sub-apps included in the same way]

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    # [ssl stuff]
}
```

I also tried to replace the separate locations with

```
location ^~ /(sub1|sub2)/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/index.php?$query_string;
}`
```

but didn't succeed with that - this location somehow didn't ever match and everything got passed to the `/index.php` in base instead.